# searchable not working and display filtered result

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have implemented searchable using SwiftUI, but it's not working, can anyone spots where the issue is, my app showing all items even when I type text in search bar not showing the result for some reason.
here is my code:

```
@State var search = ""

var searchResults: [Game] {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        return gameList.games
    } else {
        return gameList.games.filter { $0.name.contains(search.lowercased()) }
    }
}
init() {
        self.gameList.reload()
    }
    var body: some View {
        let columns = [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
        ]
        NavigationView {
            if gameList.isLoading {
            FourSquares()

            
        } else {
            ScrollView {
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    
                    ForEach(searchResults) { (game: Game) in
                        NavigationLink(destination: GameDetailView(gameId: game.id)) {
                            GameRowView(game: game)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
                    
                })
                .id(UUID())

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Upcoming Games", displayMode: .automatic)

        }
    }
    .environmentObject(favorites)
    .searchable(text: $search)
    .refreshable { self.gameList.reload() }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
 }
}
```

I'm using SwiftUI for iOS 15 and 16 and using Xcode 14

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if search.isEmpty {` ? Where does `searchText` come from?

Comment: @vadian yeah sorry that was another var for debugging. thank you very much it works now